# Login user with credentials stored in mongo database node & express

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, passport.js

I have been trying many methods, and using Passport middleware has gotten me the furthest with this task. I think i am missing some final step for this to be running properly, I have no errors right now. Here is my code:

I have a login.component.html

```
<form method="POST" action="login">
  Username: <input type="text" name="username" required>
  Password: <input type="text" name="password" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

User model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let user = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});


const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', user);
```

User route:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');


let User = require('../models/user');

//Login form
router.get('/login', function(req, res)
{
    res.render('login');
})

//Login process
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next)
{
    passport.authenticate('local',
    {
        successRedirect: '/admin',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true
    })(req,res,next);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Passport.js

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config/db');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs'); 

module.exports = function(passport)
{
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done)
    {
        let query = {username:username};
        User.findOne(query, function(err, User)
        {
            if(err) throw err;

            if(!User)
            {
                return done(null, false, {message: 'No user found'});
            }

            bcrypt.compare(password, User.password, function(err, isMatch)
            {
                if(err) throw err;

                if(isMatch)
                {
                    return done(null, User);
                }
                else
                {
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Wrong pass'});
                }
            });

        }); 
    }));

    passport.serializeUser(function(User,done)
    {
        done(null, User.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done)
    {
        User.findById(id, function(err, User)
        {
            done(err, User);
        });
    });
}
```

I have been working on this for hours, to no avail. Would be great if someone could give me some help or point me in my next steps to get this too work properly.

I feel like i'm missing something but not sure what. I havent changed any code inside my login.component.ts, that may be the reason the code doesnt do what i want it to do.

Heres the login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private router: Router, ) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your user route, if you want to subscribe from the POST /login on your Angular app and use its response for future reference, you can do so without the redirection and just return its response

**User route:**

```
//Login process
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next)
{
    passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!user) return res.status(404).json('No user found');   // Or err.message / err.info depends on the passed error message you had set

        req.logIn(user, err => {
           if (err) next(err);
           else res.status(200).json(user);     // Return user object from successfully fetched passport user auth
        });
   })(req, res, next);
});
```

**User Service:**

```
  signIn(credentials: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
       .post('http://localhost:3000/auth/login', credentials)   // Or any url you had set.
       .map((response: any) => response);
  }
```

**Login Component**

```
login(credentials: any): void {       // You can either pass credentials or not as you can also access it inside your component with 'this.form.value'
   this.userService
      .signIn(credentials)
      .subscribe(
         response => {
            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));  // Optional; Store your user/token response on the localStorage for future reference.
             this.router.navigate([ "/home" ]);                  // Navigate to the next page after user is authenticated
         },
      error => console.error(error)
      );
}
```

Comment: for the login component, would i place the code in ngOnInit(){} ?

Comment: Had updated my answer. You must place it in a separate function (login function) so that when you had submitted your login form or clicked the submit button, you can call the login() function to process the credentials.